# How do I get a global function recognized by my JS file loaded through AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, xmlhttprequest, global

I'm confused about scopes in Javascript and how to get a global function recognized.  On my page I have

```
<script src="base64.js"></script>
```

defined.  Then in another file, I have

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
...
        var full = location.protocol+'//'+location.hostname+(location.port ? ':'+location.port: '');
            alert(Base64.decode("abc"));
        xhr.open("get", full + "myotherfile.js", true);
        xhr.send()
```

The alert executes without a problem.  However in the "mytoherfile.js" references to the Base64 class result in a RerefernceError.  So at the top of my myotherfile.js I tried

```
import {Base64} from 'base64';
```

but this results in a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" error.  What's the right way to include get my global function recognized in a JS file loaded through AJAX?

**Edit:** The remote loaded JS file is loaded using

```
this.worker = new Worker(xhrResponseText);
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with Scopes. One is a ES6 import statement which is invalid in browser and needs to be transpiled to ES5 which the browser understand. But you have not given enough context in your question. You need to tell how you are are including this `mytoherfile` and are you just using browser or what?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, Yes I'm just using a browser, no NodeJS stuff.

Comment: So you get the js file with ajax but how do you execute it?

Comment: You're trying to import Base64, but did you exported it after loaded thru ajax?

Comment: @Musa, The file is loaded using a web worker -- "this.worker = new Worker(xhrResponseText);", in which the xhrResponseText is the AJAX response text from teh remote call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts loaded in the main page are not available in web workers, you have to import them with `importScripts` not the import command

```
importScripts("base64.js");
```

Comment: Ok, so despite the fact taht "http://localhost:3000/assets/BigInteger.min.js" loads in my browser just fine, when I try "importScripts("/assets/BigInteger.min.js");", I get a "SyntaxError: Failed to load worker script at "/assets/BigInteger.min.js" error.  Any thoughts about this?

Comment: Irs the line you listed -- "importScripts("/assets/BigInteger.min.js");".  That's what's causing the error.  Is it complaining about the path?  Not sure what the error means and there's no other information.

Comment: Does BigInteger.min.js try to access the dom or the window object?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell.  It is this freeware library.  The exact location is here -- https://peterolson.github.io/BigInteger.js/BigInteger.min.js .  Is that a restriction of the importScripts directive -- that whatever it accesses should not reference the dom or window object?

Comment: Just grasping at straws really, I tried importing the script in a web worker and I got an error but if I use the GitHub URL it worked, not sure why

Comment: Yeah I notice this too.  The absolute URL works but when I try and import wiht a relative path I get errors.  Hmmm

Answer (score -1):

In old-fashioned (non-module) javascript files, global variables are implied to be made on window. So in the first example, `Base64.decode("abc")` is the same as `window.Base64.decode("abc")`. In modules, however, this is not true. If you want to access a global variable on the window, it must be done explicitly.

In the module, try changing the reference to `Base64` to `window.Base64`.

Sidenote: If the `base64.js` file works with a basic script tag import, then it will not work to import it as an es6 module like you have done (`import {Base64} from 'base64';`). You can read up more on how to import modules [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)!

Hope that helps!

#### Update

For clarity, here are a couple examples. Basically, what ever you put in the curly braces (`{ Base64}`) must be exported from the script being imported, not placed on the window.

```
<script src=".../base64.js"></script>

<script>
  // both are accessible this way because this is NOT a module
  // and global variables are assumed to be on the window.
  console.log(Base64);
  console.log(window.Base64);
</script>

<script type="module">
  // Will not work:
  // import { Base64 } from ".../base64.js
  // import { window.Base64 } from ".../base64.js

  // The same as importing view the script tag
  // (not needed because the script tag already imported it)
  // import ".../base64.js"

  // the "global variable" is accessible on the window
  console.log(window.Base64)
</script>
```

Comment: The error is occuring on this line -- "import {Base64} from 'base64';".  Chagning the line to "import {window.Base64} from 'base64';" still results in the same syntax error.  Note that these are files loaded in a browser (that is, not NodeJS stuff)

Comment: @Dave Hey! Sorry for being unclear. I just updated the answer with some examples and more comments. Let me know if makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification although when I try prefixing withi "window." in my AJAX loaded JS file, I get the error, "window is not defined".

Answer (score -2):

The issue is with the path you are referring to. Here are valid paths in type module.

```
// Supported:
import {foo} from 'https://jakearchibald.com/utils/bar.js';
import {foo} from '/utils/bar.js';
import {foo} from './bar.js';
import {foo} from '../bar.js';

// Not supported:
import {foo} from 'bar.js';
import {foo} from 'utils/bar.js';
```

Try referring to the path directly. something like this

```
import {addTextToBody} from '../../someFolder/someOtherfolder/utils.js';
```

here are valid pathName

```
Starts with ./  :- same folder
Starts with ../ :- Parent folder
Starts with ../../ :- above parentfolder
```

Comment: I'm using in-browser JS, NOT node.  Anyhow, when I tried your line "var allBase64Methods = require("/assets/BigInteger.min.js")", I got the error "ReferenceError: require is not defined".  Similarly this line "import {bigInt} from '/assets/BigInteger.min.js';" results in a "SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module" error.  Keep in mind this is loaded through a web worker.

Comment: can you open this link in your browser and confim me wather its showing that the browser is supported. https://cdn.rawgit.com/jakearchibald/6110fb6df717ebca44c2e40814cc12af/raw/7fc79ed89199c2512a4579c9a3ba19f72c219bd8/

Comment: Hi, I opened your link and see the message "This browser supports modules!".  The error messages I was receiving don't point to a path issue.  Why do you think this is a path issue?

Comment: That is because module yet not supports bare import specifiers. I posted the valid paths that the module support in the awnser... Did you try providing the direct path ... If you find any problem adding path insert a picture with ur filre tree pointing to the active folder i will update the correct path